# Assembly function called from c is ignored

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I am calling a function called `fpow` which is implemented in ARM assembly.

```
extern float fpow(float x, float y);

int main()
{
    //...
    R = fpow(x, y);
    //...
}
```

The problem is that R contains x after the call. It seems like the function is not doing anything and since r0 is the return register it looks like fpow is returning x.

Here is the ARM assembly implementation:

```
.globl fpow

fpow: 

  stmfd sp!, {r4, r5, r6, lr} 


  mov r4, r0 
  mov r5, r1 


  mov r1, #0 

  bl __aeabi_fcmpeq 
  ...      
  bl __aeabi_fmul 
  bl pow2 
  ldmfd sp!, {r4, r5, r6, pc}
```

Comment: That implementation looks completely plausible.  What is the part within `...`? Did you make sure both functions use the same ABI with respect to hard/soft float?

Comment: `powf` is not the same as `fpow`. And it seems like `fpow` is going to return whatever `pow2` returns.

Comment: `powf`, are you sure that that's not a macro you are calling or that a builtin function is used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What options are you using to compile your C?  Are you using `-mfloat-abi=hard` or `soft`?

If `soft`, the C compiler will expect the `fpow` return value as a `float` (IEEE binary32) bit-pattern in `r0`.

A calling-convention mismatch would explain seeing the first arg as return value:

If the C compiler's asm is using the `hard` float-ABI, the first FP arg-passing register (`s0`) is also the FP single-precision return-value register.  If your hand-written asm is written for the `soft` float ABI, it won't modify `s0`.

Answer (score 1):

Your extern declares powf but you call (and appear to implement fpow). Fix it so that all three match, Right now I suspect (though am not certain) that you are running into an issue with C's handling of undeclared functions.

Comment: That was a typo in the question. It wouldn't link if the names don't match.

Comment: @Shiro you can't have typo in your question, if you prepare [mcve] (including the "verify" part of it).

Comment: Of course you can. Otherwise there wouldn't be any errors if you just "verify" it.

Comment: If so, this answers your exact question and you should accept it.

Comment: @Shiro you probably misunderstood the "verify" part... you create a minimal example where the error can be reproduced, and you "verify" you can reproduce it (it compiles and it runs as intended = it demonstrates the problem you are interested into, and not some other compile/linking/run time error you didn't want to ask about). Your example is nicely minified, but you failed to make it fully runnable for others (including yourself), and you failed to verify it can build and has same problem like you wanted to ask about (while it has linking error instead due to typo = causing unwanted answer).